# How to calculate cooling time of a sphere when only knowing T_start, t_ambiant, and the material of the sphere?

Tags: time, cooling

I'm helping an artist making a giant gel blob and we wanna know how long it takes for it to cool down. For simplicity let's assume its a uniformly heated (T_start = 70 degrees) water sphere (radius = 1 m) and the ambient temperature is constant all the way around it at say T_ambient = 25 degrees celciuls. How long would it take to cool it to 30 degrees?  I asume the gradiant will change over time and make a decreasing exponential function and asymptotically aproch 25 degrees eventualy. But how long for it to reach 30 degrees starting at 70?

Since I don't know aleady how long it will take I guess I can't use newtons cooling law since I can't calculate the cooling coeficient without knowing the cooling time or can I?. Or can I look up the coeficient up somewhere?
or is there an other way?
(it would be nice to know how time depends on radius or on mass? )
I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEyOk4brcZg
But here i again need some coeficients.

Comment: With large pieces of art, it is important to try some smaller test pieces first and work up to full size. This will answer important questions like "Will it collapse under its own weight?"

Comment: @mmesser314 hi :)  thank you for your comment. yes good idea, we are currently making small tests. And it's very interesting if it will hold as it gets larger. :)

Comment: @mmesser314 do you know something about cooling?

Comment: Newton's law of cooling is probably appropriate, but it bundles a lot of complicated interactions into the coefficient; the three data you have are not sufficient to even look up a benchmark value on a table. You're going to need to do some measurements.

Comment: I upvoted the question, but I really want to downvote based on the spelling/grammar. If you want more people to answer it might help to take a little time and edit the body of your question. I edited out the superfluous chatty stuff for you, but not all the other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a neat project.

The terms you want search for is probably [Transient heat conduction of a sphere](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-94-007-2739-7_400#Sec201424). The link is similar to the you tube video. In terms of heat transfer I think:

1. Radiation terms are mostly negligible. You can check with this hyperphysics link.[Hyperphysics cooling calculator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html#c2)
2. Convection will be important - so if you cool with a fan you will get a different rate than if it is just natural conduction.
3. Conduction could be important. - You don't describe how the gel is held. So if it is in a spherical shell you have an additional layer and boundary condition. If there is a lot of contact with the floor or some kind of base then you could lose heat through the base.
4. Not knowing anything about how you make your gel if the sphere is large you could get some type of convection in the container initially.
5. As the gel goes from being a liquid to a gel, the heat transfer properties are likely to change, so this in detail could be a nonlinear problem.
6. If you spray cooler water on it, or otherwise speed up the cooling by using a fan analytically the problem is more difficult becasue of evaporation or the convection coefficient being different on different points of the sphere.

Since you are trying to make a blob, perhaps the above doesn't matter a lot if all you want is a quick estimate. In that case Newtons law of cooling is perhaps not a bad way to go, for at least smaller blobs. You also have the curves from the analytical solution, so you might be able to do a couple of experiments and get a rough idea.

[Wolfram has a calculator](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TransientCoolingOfASphere/) but you would still need to figure out the coefficients you want to plug into the calculator.

I haven't used it for heat transfer, but Fusion 360 is free software and it has a thermal module that includes convection, it might be suitable for problem like this.